# I was trying to pass a parameter from from view to another ,But I am getting a wrong output?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

What I am trying to do is , initially  print this table:-

```
id   content     from     to     have_read    created_at     updated_at
1      xyz        xxx     qwe       0           xxxx          xxxx
2      xyz        xxx     yyy       1           xxxx          xxxx
3      xyt        xxx     xxx       0           xxxx          xxxx
```

When the user clicks on any id , it will link to a new page . And there it will display all the details of the row selected .

This my html file for the table:-

```
<% @messages.each do |m| %>
 <% if m.to == get_user %> 

  <tr>
    <td><font color="blue"><%= link_to m.id, show_message_path(m) %></font></td>
    <td><%=m.from%></td>
    <td><%=m.subject%></td>
    <td><%=m.created_at%></td>
  </tr>

 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am using " show_message_path(m)" so that it will pass the selected row.

My controller is :-

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def new
   @messages = Message.all
  end


  def show_message
   @messages = Message.find_by(params[:id])
  end

end
```

This the contents of show_message.html.erb :-

```
<h1><%=@messages.id%></h1>
```

I noticed that the id printed is always '1' irrespective of what row I selected .

I have used a similare method for another project , and it worked fine there . I dont where i went wrong.

This is my routes.rd file:-

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'messages/new'

  root                'static_pages#home'
  get    'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
  get    'about'   => 'static_pages#about'
  get    'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get    'signup'  => 'users#new'
  get    'newmain'  => 'users#newmain'  
  get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
  post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
  get 'show_message' => 'messages#show_message'
  resources :users
   resources :messages
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
get 'show_message' => 'messages#show_message'
```

to

```
get 'show_message/:id' => 'messages#show_message',
```